# Locked convex polyhedra

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry, convex-geometry

Call a set of polyhedra *free* if it is possible to rigidly move the polyhedra, without any polyhedron intersecting any other, so that their pairwise distances are arbitrary large, and *locked* otherwise. So two linked tori are locked, as is a ship in a bottle.

Can a finite set of *convex* polyhedra in $\mathbb{R}^3$ ever be locked?

note: We can move these polyhedra simultaneously.

Comment: Can't this easily be done by first moving "outermost" polyhedra to very far distances or something?

Comment: @Batominovski Right, the answer is "obviously" yes, and it's enough to show that you can always peel off one "outer" polyhedron. But a proof is not so obvious to me...

Comment: Must we move the objects one by one, or can we move them simultaneously?

Comment: @Batominovski Unclear in the original question, but I think the intent was to allow simultaneous movement.

Comment: Then consider a series of "dilations" about any fixed point that shifts only the barycenters of the polyhedra, but do not change their sizes or orientations.

Comment: Peeling one by one looks trivial, but to prove rigorously, I haven't yet come up with an idea.

Comment: @Batominovski We can simultaneously move them. Actually I can find an example that we cannot take out any one of these polyhedra only by moving itself. Maybe this problem isn't very "obviously".

Comment: Would you mind posting that example in the answer area?

Comment: Do we know if this is true of $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: @Batominovski My description of the example maybe not very clear.

Comment: @MiloBrandt I guess in $\mathbb{R^2}$ this kind of finite set isn't exist. But I can't prove it.

Answer (score 6):

Summarizing some of the answers and comments given so far,
with some followup on the links provided therein:

It is possible to construct a set of finitely many convex polytopes
in $\mathbb R^3$ such that no single polytope can be removed from the set
without at some point intersecting another polytope.
This is Exercise 42.47(e) of 
[*Lectures on Discrete and Polyhedral Geometry,* by
Igor Pak](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/geompol8.pdf),
stated on page 376 and solved on page 409.
Another such construction is illustrated on [this page](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/nest/imager/contributions/snoeyink/sculpt/theorem.html)
from "Objects that cannot be taken apart with two hands,"
by Jack Snoeyink (snoeyink@cs.ubc.ca).
Another reference is: J. Snoeyink  and J. Stolfi, Objects that cannot be  taken apart with two hands, *Discrete Comput. Geom.* 12 (1994), 367–384.

It is possible to construct a set of finitely many convex polytopes
such that no proper subset of them can be removed by moving the
entire subset as a group
("taking apart the polytopes with two hands").
This is Exercise 42.47(h) of the above-mentioned 
*Lectures on Discrete and Polyhedral Geometry.*
An example is illustrated on [the above-mentioned
page by Jack Snoeyink](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/nest/imager/contributions/snoeyink/sculpt/theorem.html).

If we are allowed to move *all* polytopes independently and simultaneously,
that is, for a set of $n$ polytopes we may try to 
take it apart with $n$ hands, any set of polytopes can be taken apart
as follows.
Choose a point inside each polytope. Perform a dilation of those
$n$ selected points away from a common center.
Translate each polytope so that the selected point 
within that polytope follows that dilation.
(In other words, we can "explode" the set of polytopes.)

Some mechanical puzzles are manufactured that (theoretically)
require $n$ hands to take apart and to reassemble.

Comment: But this still leaves the question about moving multiple objects one-by-one unanswered.  By that, I mean: shifting the polyhedra one after another slightly, but not necessarily unlocking them from the set, until it is possible to take out some object(s).

Comment: @Batominovski If the objects are initially not touching, and you are allowed an arbitrary number of "moves" before unlocking any piece, I believe you can perform the "explosion" by moving each piece (one at a time) a tiny distance in the direction the dilation would take it, repeating this as often as needed.

Comment: That is what I conjecture (with the assumption that there are no touching objects).  But it seems very difficult to prove.  (Anyway, in my definition, polyhedra are closed sets.  So the disjointness assumption already implies that each can be moved slightly.)

Comment: I think it is not too hard to prove, actually. Technically, I suppose this is a new question, since the rules on moving pieces are quite different (only one at a time, but multiple moves of each piece allowed, as opposed to each piece can be moved simultaneously, but only once), even though the obvious proof is really just a variation on the "explosion" method.

Comment: Really good answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is an exercise 42.47 in [my book](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/book.htm).  Briefly, if you are allowed to move all polyhedra simultaneously, you can always unlock them.  If you are allowed to move only one at a time, you cannot (see refs in the book).

Comment: One of the comments on the question suggests a method of independently translating all the polyhedra simultaneously, each by a different vector. In the spirit of your definition of "take apart with two hands", I would call the suggested method "taking apart with $n$ hands" for arbitrary $n$. It seems trivial that all configurations of polyhedra can be taken apart if $n$ hands are allowed.

Comment: Wow. It must be an excellent book. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this example is correct, but only by moving one polyhedron, we cannot "take out" anyone of them.

Regular tetrahedron has four surface. We cut away them and move outward slightly. So we have 4 piece of regular triangles in the space, they are not intersect, but they are sufficiently close. Now we can consider these triangles are polyhedron with very short thickness.

In the gap of those triangles, we put 12 pyramids pass through it. The bottom of these pyramids are bit larger than the gap, so we can't take out any pyramid. For each edge of triangles, we can set one of those pyramids lean to it. Every triangle also can't be taken out because it was stuck by 3 pyramids. So we can't take out any of them(including triangles and pyramids) only by moving itself.

Comment: Can't you first move the twelve pyramids, one-by-one, slightly so they are no longer blocking the triangles?

Comment: I don't think this works as described. In order to "lean" the pyramids far enough to block the triangles from being removed, you would have to make the pyramids narrow enough, or make the gaps between the triangles large enough, so that you could pull out each pyramid completely, one at a time. This is because the dihedral angle in a regular tetrahedron is less than a right angle. If you base this construction on a regular icosahedron instead, it might work, that is, the pieces might all be locked, if you allow only translation (no rotations) and allow only one piece at a time to move.

Comment: @Batominovski Sure, if we can move more than one polyhedrons, the triangles are no longer blocking.

Comment: So, we can still move the objects in your example, not simultaneously, but in a one-by-one fashion, and take them apart, right?  This is what I had in mind when I first commented on your question.  While it "looks obvious" that no finite locked set of polyhedra exists (in this one-by-one case), a proof doesn't seem easy at all.

Comment: @DavidK We can let these pyramids sufficiently long and thin, so the lean angle of pyramids could be sufficiently small and it also can block the triangles.

Comment: @Batominovski Yes, you are right. If we can move more than one polyhedrons, even not simultaneously, we could also separate them. The answer of the original problem looks really "obvious", but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Because of the dihedral angle of the tetrahedron, If we lean the thin pyramids far enough so that they actually prevent removing a triangle, the other triangle blocks us from extending the thin pyramid very far into the space between the triangles. In fact each pyramid can easily be removed by translating it along a line perpendicular to the triangle it is supposed to block. If you draw this from a viewpoint looking perpendicularly at one of the triangles, this may be more obvious.

Comment: @DavidK I see what you mean. So, if we use this construction on a polyhedron which every dihedral angle sufficiently close to $\pi$, it might work?

Comment: Yes, I think it could be made to work. I think you just need the angle to be greater than $\pi/2$, so a regular icosahedron should be a suitable figure to start with.

Comment: So The answer of the original problem may not  be obvious.